# Как задать параметры в виртуальное окружение при запуске compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня в yml-файле лежит несколько сервисов и у одного из них указаны логины и пароли:

```
 db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-db-ai
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "my_root_pass_awevr33qrbevJ"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "my_db"
      MYSQL_USER: "my_user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "my_user_pass_aevraervaev"
    ports:
      - 3310:3306
```

Можно ли их убрать в строку консоли при поднятии:

```
doker-compose up -d
```

При запуске докера это делается так:

```
docker run -e NAME_PARAM=<value> <image_name>
```

Можно ли что-то такое реализовать, при запуске **docker-compose**? Или придется каждый контейнер поднимать вручную и прокидывать конфиги?